# What can I mix and store Kimchi in?

Tags: fermentation, sauerkraut, kimchi, containers

I'm looking for ways I can use containers to mix and store kimchi from the thrift store.  I don't want to buy special containers, unless I have to.  I've seen plastic bowls and the like used to mix kimchi or when you do that initial salting (I've never made it, only watched others).  After that I wondered if I could use things like canisters with lock lid or plain plastic (kitchen) containers.  I'm sure you've been to a thrift store, so you can imagine the hodgepodge of possibilities.

I wanted to make sauerkraut too, and thought the lockdown canister might work? Maybe if I didn't lock it? Those crocks are expensive.

Comment: We have http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/61691/best-container-for-making-sauerkraut - I don't know enough about kimchi to say if it is a duplicate, hopefully the community will be able to say

Comment: As @rumtscho points out, 61691 responds to the question, as the mechanism (lactic fermentation) is the same in both cases, but I'll also add that special containers are not necessary.  Almost any container will work.

Answer (score 3):

To mix, use any bowl that won't be damaged by the salt.  I would stay away from metal or wood, anything else would be fine.

To store,  just use a glass jar. I usually use a half gallon canning jar, but if you're making a lot you can use a gallon jar.

Cover the cabbage with a big flat cabbage leaf.  (Or a grape leaf).  Press down, so the leaf is covered with brine. Next you just need a weight. What I like to use for this is a plastic bag: get a big one(like the kind you put produce in at the grocery store), and fill with some water.  Put that in your jar on top of the cabbage leaf, being careful not to spill any water.

Answer (score 1):

I would mix in stainless steel,plastic or glass bowel and store in glass or ceramic container that has been glazed in side !